# Is is possible to determine if a method was called via a property in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, deprecation-warning

#### Summary

Is it possible to determine if a method was called via a property rather than called directly?

#### Details

I'm making some API changes to some code: The old API used Getters and Setters (`GetAttr` and `SetAttr`) and the new public API will use `x.Attr` and `x.Attr = val` respectively. I want to add deprecation warnings when programmers call `GetAttr()`

Effectively, I'm looking for is this magic `_was called_via_property` function:

```
import warnings

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._attr = None

    def GetAttr(self):
        if not _was_called_via_property():
            warnings.warn("`GetAttr()` is deprecated. Use `x.attr` property instead.", DeprecationWarning)
        return self._attr

    def SetAttr(self, value):
        if not _was_called_via_property():
            warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
        self._attr = value

    Attr = property(GetAttr, SetAttr)
```

Ideally the solution would also work if things are defined via decorators in addition to the `property()` function, but it's not required.

Like so:

```
@property
def attr(self):
    if not _was_called_via_property():
       warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
    return self._attr

@attr.setter
def attr(self, value):
    if not _was_called_via_property():
        warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
    self._attr = value
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. Ah well. I have a backup plan, I just don't want to do it because I'm lazy :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't distinguish `property` descriptor access from direct access, no.

Create a proper property, and have the old methods proxy for it:

```
@property
def attr(self):
    return self._attr

@property.setter
def attr(self, value):
    self._attr = value

# legacy access to the attr property
def GetAttr(self):
   warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
   return self.attr

def SetAttr(self, value):
   warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
   self.attr = value
```

Comment: Yup, that was the backup plan.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to wrap `property`:

```
def myprop(getter, setter):
    return property(lambda self : getter(self, True), 
                    lambda self, x : setter(self, x, True))


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._attr = None

    def GetAttr(self, called_via_property=False):
        if not called_via_property:
            warnings.warn("`GetAttr()` is deprecated. Use `x.attr` property instead.", DeprecationWarning)
        return self._attr

    def SetAttr(self, value, called_via_property=False):
        if not called_via_property:
            warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
        self._attr = value

    Attr = myprop(GetAttr, SetAttr)
```

Another solution could be to override `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` to generate getters and setters with warning, something like:

```
class MyBase(object):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
         if key.startswith("Get"):
              tail = key[3:]
              if hasattr(self, tail):
                   def getter(self):
                        res = getattr(self, tail)
                        issue_warning()
                        return res
                   return lambda : getter(self)
         raise AttributeError
```

and similar for the setter.